# Function invocation of postgresql database from java program

Tags: java, database, arrays, postgresql, arraylist

There is a Postgresql database with the following function stub

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION net_train(terms text[], perceptron_id integer)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$begin
-- stub
end;$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION net_train(text[], integer)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

How by a call in java to the program to transfer an array of terms (also it would be desirable to know as to transfer the second parameter) to this function? The input array of terms is written in

```
ArrayList<String> ProcessedTherms = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Answer (score 1):

We used ibatis for mapping, but it should be similar:

```
Connection conn = ps.getConnection(); //ps is prepared statement
ArrayList arr = (ArrayList) param;
final Array sqlArray = conn.createArrayOf("integer", arr.toArray()); // we had integers, should be similar for String
ps.setArray(i, sqlArray);// i is position of parameter
```